# How to show real time progress to the user, when uploading a file with SCP in python

Tags: python, ssh, popen, scp, pexpect

In python I am using pexpect and ssh to log into a device, however I must use SCP to load an IOS onto the device.  I want to show the user the progress of the file being uploaded in real time.  I would assume this would be easiest through Popen, I am learning python as I write it.  This is a new one to me, what would be the proper syntax for using Popen to show the user the progress of the SCP upload?

Comment: You need to dig into the documentation of the `subprocess` module and then make sure that you properly parse stdout/stderr of the scp process.

Comment: I have been reading into the subprocess module, I understand that stdout is probably going to be what gets me my progress in real time.  My problem is implimenting it with scp, I have only seen one example and that person was asking what they were doing wrong; with no answer back.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I learned that if I use os.system() with my scp command it shows what I need it to show.  There is probably also a way to do it through subprocess.Popen, but I needed a quick solution.

Comment: this is relevant - http://askubuntu.com/questions/44059/progress-bar-in-scp-command